# Regarding the display of parameters in URL

Tags: .net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Vidly1.Models;

namespace Vidly1.Controllers
{
    public class MoviesController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Movies
        public ActionResult Random()
        {
            var movie = new Movie() { Name = "Shrek!" };
            //return View(movie);
            //return Content("Hello world");
            //return HttpNotFound();
            //return new EmptyResult();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { page= 1, sortBy = "name" });
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above when I run the application I dont see the parameters in the url. I am new to .Net and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you please include the definition of the `Index` method on `HomeController`? If you've customised your routes, it may be worth including the content of your `MapRoute` call too.

Comment: It is working now. I made no changes to the code but is working fine now. However could you please explain what you meant by definition of Index. I am following .Net course offered by Udemy and the instructor just mentioned "Index" as the name of the action. Thanks for taking a look at the code :)

Comment: I just meant that it would be easier to diagnose if you showed the code from `public ActionResult Index()` method in the `HomeController` in your question, but you're OK now anyway!